# Как выбрать сразу несколько элементов списка

Tags: javascript, jquery, случайные-числа

Привет!

Подскажите новичку, как выбрать сразу несколько элементов из списка по их индексу и присвоить им класс?

Имеем следующий код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Объявляем переменные
  var listitems = jQuery(".list li"); //Элементы списка правого блока

  //Получаем кол-во элементов списка правого блока
  var total = listitems.length;

  //Получаем рандомное число от 1 до кол-ва элементов списка
  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  };
  var willSelect = getRandomInt(1, total); //Рандомное число

  //Получаем массив с рандомным количеством элементов списка
  var randArray = []; // массив, в котором будем хранить уникальные числа
  var i = 0; // индекс для массива
  var countNum = willSelect; // количество нужных чисел
  var max = total; // максимальное число
  var min = 1; // минимальное  число

  // цикл, пока не получим массив с уникальными числами
  while (i < countNum) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; // генерируем случайное число
    if (find(randArray, rand) == 0) { // Проверяем уникальность числа
      randArray[i] = rand; // если уникальное, то заисываем его в массив
      i++;
    }

  };

  // проверяем вхождение в массив
  function randCheck(array, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] == value) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  };

  //Мы получили массив, с рандомными целыми уникальными числами.
  var willSelect = randArray;

  $("list li") / код / .addClass("black");

});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.list {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  margin: 0;
}
.list li {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
}
.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
  </div
```

В итоговом массиве мы получили "порядковые номера" элементов li, к которым нужно добавить класс .black. Так вот, как добавить его сразу к нескольким элементам?
each?

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А к каким конкретно то нужно добавить класс? с какой-то определенной цифрой ? чем определяется то, что элементу нужно добавить класс?

Comment: Класс нужно добавить к рандомному количеству рандомных элементов списка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем ответ - да. Надо пробегать в массиве:

```
$(".list li").each(function(index, element) {
    if (willSelect.indexOf(index + 1) != -1) {
        $(this).addClass('black');      
    }    
});
```

Полный код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Объявляем переменные
  var listitems = jQuery(".list li"); //Элементы списка правого блока

  //Получаем кол-во элементов списка правого блока
  var total = listitems.length;

  //Получаем рандомное число от 1 до кол-ва элементов списка
  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  };
  var willSelect = getRandomInt(1, total); //Рандомное число

  //Получаем массив с рандомным количеством элементов списка
  var randArray = []; // массив, в котором будем хранить уникальные числа
  var i = 0; // индекс для массива
  var countNum = willSelect; // количество нужных чисел
  var max = total; // максимальное число
  var min = 1; // минимальное  число

  // цикл, пока не получим массив с уникальными числами
  while (i < countNum) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; // генерируем случайное число
    if (find(randArray, rand) == 0) { // Проверяем уникальность числа
      randArray[i] = rand; // если уникальное, то заисываем его в массив
      i++;
    }

  };

  // проверяем вхождение в массив
  function randCheck(array, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] == value) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  };

  //Мы получили массив, с рандомными целыми уникальными числами.
  var willSelect = randArray;
  
  $(".list li").each(function(index, element) {
    if (willSelect.indexOf(index + 1) != -1) {
      $(this).addClass('black');      
    }    
  });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.list {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  margin: 0;
}
.list li {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
}
.list li.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Изменил в `css` стиль `.black` на `.list li.black` - иначе он не будет срабатывать из-за перекрытия стилем `.list li`

---

Рекомендация: при генерации чисел сделать еще проверку на то, что такое число уже было сгенерированно. Так как у вас может сгенерироваться массив с дубликатами, типа:

1, 4, 7, 2, 9, 2

Конечно при применении стиля - это никак не повлияет. Но в любом случае это неправильно. Да и могут возникнуть проблемы в где-нибудь в другом месте, если например ожидалось выделение пяти элементов, а выделилось два. И прочее...

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все работает. Проверку уже добавил.